# How to add SD to a geom_line if it uses predictions that are in a separate table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I have a data frame (data.frame.2) with my fitted values from a model and a data frame (data.frame.1) with my observations. The fitted values are shown with `geom_line` and the observations with `geom_point`. That works well. I have calculated SD values of the fitted values stored in data.frame.1, together with the fitted values.

This is working:

```
data.frame.1 %>%
 ggplot(aes(my_x, my_y, col = my_groups)) +
 geom_point() +
 geom_line(
  data = data.frame.2,
  aes(y = .fitted)
  )
```

This is not working:

```
data.frame.1 %>%
 ggplot(aes(my_x, my_y, col = my_groups)) +
 geom_point() +
 geom_line(
  data = data.frame.2,
  aes(y = .fitted)
  ) +
 geom_errorbar(
  data = data.frame.2,
  aes(
   ymin = .fitted - SD.fitted,
   ymax = .fitted + SD.fitted
   )
  )
```

R complains that "my_y" is not provided, but that seems not to be a problem for `geom_line`, as data.frame.2 does not contain "my_y". What do I have to change?

I work with 2 data frames because "my_y" has 10 observations that are plotted as points.
The corresponding .fitted plotted with geom_line has ~3000 values in order to get a smooth curve. I am very sorry that I could not provide a reprex this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried moving the `aes` from `ggplot()` to `geom_point()` like this? I can't test if this works without some data

```
data.frame.1 %>%
 ggplot() +
 geom_point(aes(my_x, my_y, col = my_groups)) +
 geom_line(
  data = data.frame.2,
  aes(y = .fitted)
  ) +
 geom_errorbar(
  data = data.frame.2,
  aes(
   ymin = .fitted - SD.fitted,
   ymax = .fitted + SD.fitted
   )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue, together with using ```geom_ribbon``` instead of ```geom_errorbar```.